# Multiple image subscriber failure

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made 2 nodes, publishing my web camera and external camera images.and I want to show both camera images with a single subscriber node. but when i run my subscriber node, it publishes camera 1 and 2 images alternatively.( if i run subscriber code for the first time it publishes camera 1 image and next time i run it publishes camera 2 images. not publishing at the same time) .can anyone please tell me what changes i have to make in my code.

camera1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

def webcam_pub():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('camera1', Image, queue_size=1)
    rospy.init_node('webcam_pub', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(60) # 60hz

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    bridge = CvBridge()

    if not cam.isOpened():
         sys.stdout.write("Webcam is not available")
         return -1

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        ret, frame = cam.read()
    
    
    msg = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame, encoding="bgr8")

        if ret:
            rospy.loginfo("Capturing image failed.")

        pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        webcam_pub()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
      pass
```

camera2.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

def webcam_pub():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('camera2', Image, queue_size=1)
    rospy.init_node('webcam_pub', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(60) # 60hz

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    bridge = CvBridge()

    if not cam.isOpened():
         sys.stdout.write("Webcam is not available")
         return -1

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        ret, frame = cam.read()
    
    
    msg = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame, encoding="bgr8")

        if ret:
            rospy.loginfo("Capturing image failed.")

        pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        webcam_pub()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
      pass
```

Listener.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
 
#import roslib
#roslib.load_manifest('my_package')
import sys
import rospy
import cv2
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
 
class image_converter:
 
  def __init__(self):
     self.image_pub = rospy.Publisher("image",Image,  queue_size=1)
 
     self.bridge = CvBridge()
     self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("camera2",Image,self.callback)
     self.image_sub1 = rospy.Subscriber("camera1",Image,self.callback1)

  def callback(self,data):
     try:
       cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
     except CvBridgeError as e:
       print(e)
 
    
     cv2.imshow("Camera 2", cv_image)
     cv2.waitKey(3)
 
     try:
       self.image_pub.publish(self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image, "bgr8"))
     except CvBridgeError as e:
       print(e)
  def callback1(self,data):
     try:
       cv_image1 = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
     except CvBridgeError as e:
       print(e)
 
    
     cv2.imshow("Camera 1", cv_image1)
     cv2.waitKey(3)
 
     try:
       self.image_pub.publish(self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image1, "bgr8"))
     except CvBridgeError as e:
       print(e)
 
def main(args):
   ic = image_converter()
   rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
   try:
     rospy.spin()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print("Shutting down")
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main(sys.argv)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288105/multiple-image-subscriber-failure./) by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2018-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
This is probably not the solution, but you're assigning two different subscriptions to the same `self.image_sub` member variable. That won't work.

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-04-10**:
But i tried with  `self.image_sub1` too.still not working.how can i solve this issue?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
I don't know right now, but reusing that variable is not correct in any case and won't work.

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-04-10**:
okay..thank you very much.new thing learned.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-04-10**:
I don't see anything necessarily wrong with the code (outside of what was already pointed out). Are you sure you have images published on the `camera1` and `camera2` topics? Are your callbacks actually being called?

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-04-10**:
i just updated my question..can you check again? @jarvisschultz

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-04-10**:
Does rqt_image_view show the images from both cameras on the right topics?

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-04-10**:
yes. `rqt_image_view` giving the output image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks to be the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577228/multithreaded-cv2-imshow-in-python-does-not-work  Each callback is running in a different thread which messes up imshow (and likely other highgui functions).  There are some other search results that may be more informative if you search for 'cv2 imshow threads python'.

You could save each received image to member variables and have a single thread (inside a loop with a sleep in `__init__` or maybe in a timer update) do all the imshow calls, and possibly need locks around each use or assignment to the images, but I suspect you want the imshows for quick debug purposes and don't want to do a lot of work to overcome their limitations.  If you gain confidence in your image publishers then use rqt_image_view to see that callbacks are working, or print some text information (like the width and height of the image) to stdout in the callbacks.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-04-11**:
when i run my subscriber node, it publishes camera 1 and 2 images alternatively.ie, if i run subscriber code for the first time it publishes camera 1 image and next time i run it publishes camera 2 images. not publishing at the same time.